# Javascript calling function from different window

Tags: javascript

in my code i'm opening a window to do some work (Instagram login).

After the whole process was finished, the opened window contain information I would like to pass to the "handling" window through calling a pre-defined function.

I know I can do `window.opener` to access that window, but it feels unsafe being very generic.

Is there a way that the opening window can send a handler to the opened window which will be called once the process ends?

Comment: What feels so unsafe about `window.opener`?

Comment: if the original window and the opened window are same domain and rn code you've created, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't like the fact that it is just calling the opener.. The opened window doesn't identify who opened it, and it sending it some data.. is there a way I can identify them ?